# Adding friend through Facebook Dialog iPhone

Tags: ios, fbwebdialogs

I want to make a friend request in my app using the `FBWebDialogs`
and I tried implementing the solution given through here which is:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: facebookUserId, @"id", nil];
[FBWebDialogs presentDialogModallyWithSession:nil dialog:@"friends" parameters:params handler:nil];
```

It showed the request but when I click the confirm, there is an error saying 
"Sorry, something went wrong"
We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.

I am using the latest `Facebook SDK`. Do you encounter this error also?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

the **bundle id** on developers.facebook.com need to be exactly identical to the one in your app

1. got to https://developers.facebook.com/
2. choose your app
3. got to *Settings*
4. check the *Bundle ID* (I'm not sure, but I think it's case sensitive)

[image: Bundle Id on developers.facebook.com]

Comment: Trying to implement this as well but running into the same problem. The bundle ID is identical and still does not work.